# Does this count as a loop on Möbius strip

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, mobius-band

Suppose we take the Möbius strip as $X = \frac{[0, 1]\times[0, 1]}{\sim}$ with usual equivalence relation.

If I define $\alpha: [0, 1] \rightarrow X$ by $x \rightarrow [(x, 1/2)]$, is this a loop? Because it seems to start and end at the same point, although that point is on the opposite side of the Möbius strip?

More generally, when defining a loop on a surface, does it matter if the start and end point are 'the same point' but on opposite sides of the surface?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, being on the same face or not is not here a rigorous statement: a point on the mobius strip is a point on the mobius strip. It does not belong to any of its face.

Comment: The loop represents the $g$ generator of $\pi_1(X) \approx \pi_1(S^1) \approx \mathbb Z$. Thus $g^2$ is not zero.

Comment: you are right, don't know why I stated this

Answer (score 0):

What you have written is a loop. Indeed, it is a continuous map $\alpha:[0,1]\to X$ so that $\alpha(0)=\alpha(1)$. Regarding "sides" of surfaces, you should note that the Möbius strip $X$ has only one side in some sense, and this relates to the fact that it is nonorientable. In general, however, we do not worry about sides, as it is not really well-defined to say what side of a surface a curve is on in the first place.

For instance, take the equator of $S^2$. Which side of $S^2$ is this on?

Comment: Thanks. It is confusing because if you physically drew the loop I describe on a Mobius strip made from paper it would not look like it started and ended at the the same point. Whereas in the case of S2 it would. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think your confusion is coming from thinking of a person walking along that loop, in which case they end up standing on the opposite side of the sheet, so to say. However, a curve does not come with such a datum, so you only really have to consider the condition of the start point equalling the end point as points in the set $X$.

Comment: Yes exactly. So the person wouldn't feel like they 'started and ended at the same point'.

Comment: Your intuition is correct, but you need to add extra information. You can think of the person as being a unit normal vector to the surface being transported along the curve. The conclusion this leads us to is that going around your loop changes the orientation of the normal vector we chose, i.e. $N$ at $\alpha(0)$ will be transformed into its reflection through $X$ at $\alpha(1)=\alpha(0)$.